# Google plus one button error

Tags: google-plus-one

I have provided the Google plus button in my website. When I click on it,  the count increments then decrements and shows an error symbol (a red exclamation mark). For a few days it was working fine, but now it is behaving like this.

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing happen on one of my sites, but the other way around.  First it wasn't working, then after a few days it worked again.  Since then I haven't seen any problems with it.  I hadn't done anything to fix it (although I tried).  I looked around the internet and read through the Google docs on the subject, but the only "help" I found was that you need to make sure that your profiles are not being blocked. Which profile wasn't clear, whether it be the user's profile or the site's profile, but I checked both (and they weren't blocked, as far as I could tell).  I wasn't all that surprised, though, as they are still working out the kinks.

If no one else comes up with a solution, just give it a couple of days before you tackle the problem again.  I'll keep an eye on this question, because I'd like to hear in the end how your problem works out.

Comment: I have found that if i change the "href" url from https to http it is working fine.why is it so

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have read that somewhere. Sorry I didn't think of that.  In my case, however, that wasn't the issue.  I never took it off https, and I just checked it again and it still works for me.  Mabye they have a waiting period before it gets activated?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem today on only one of many pages.

When exploring the issue more thoroughly I found that one of the responses included JSON with error hash containing error 400: "Invalid value".

I then figured that an image (the one with `itemprop="name"`) was containing spaces. After escaping them and other special characters, the button started working.

So, try to validate your page and make sure all values are properly escaped.

Answer (score 0):

I think that google +1 sometimes banned websites. Sometimes I have error because page is not refresh. When you add +1 you must be logged first, otherwise error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the data-href attribute so the resultant div tag will be as folows

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-href="https://google.com"></div>
```

Here I have added the "https://google.com" as a data-href value of that attribute. You can change it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error as well. For me, the error was caused by the Twitter script tag just above (in the DOM) my +1 button tag. I moved the Twitter script to the bottom of the page and the +1 button now works.  In short, it seems any sort of JS could throw this off (of course), even if the code is from a reputable site (Twitter).